# What do I need to do to get paid to Scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm a big fan of functional programming in general, Schemes in particular, and PLT-Racket ideally. I am wondering what concrete steps are likely to get me into a position where coding Scheme (or some functional language) is the bulk of the work.

I'm actually quite interested in academia, but on the other hand, I don't feel like I necessarily have  what it takes (at least not at the moment) to do a top-tier Ph.D in CS.  I definitely would prefer to have some real-world experience putting complex systems together in Scheme either way. Does anyone have any advice for an aspiring Schemer?

Comment: Is this question more suited to the programmers stack exchange?

Comment: you tell me, dog. I asked it before such a thing existed. Maybe I'll go ask it there, too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Start writing some Scheme libraries, then blog about the libraries you've wrote, get noticed in the community.

This will always give you leverage when applying for a position, employers like to have some evidence of what you can do.

Answer (score 7):

dalton has the right idea; you want to build something you can show off.  To find out about needs, you could go to http://srfi.schemers.org/, which is an archive of proposals for Scheme libraries and other improvements to Scheme, and see what you think you can contribute to.  Or make contact with the Racket team; you may be able to contribute to Racket directly.

Comment: This is a great idea- the PLT cats are pretty accessible and genuinely nice people.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to leverage something popular and in the news:  App Inventor is based on Google Blocks, which are in turn based on Kawa, which is a Scheme dialect [*].

If you can show off your skills by putting together blocks and making them available for the community...it's a natural way to take advantage both of your multi-language skills and something currently getting press coverage.

Regards,
Dak
[*] and I forgot to say that earlier, mea culpa!

Answer (score 1):

Not going to accept my own answer because it is, in general, worse than the one @dalton gave, but!

I got a grant through [Turbulence.org](http://turbulence.org) to write an art and thus was paid to scheme! Or racket, if you want to be a pedant. [repo here...](https://github.com/bd/perplex)

Answer (score 0):

F# is getting popular in the finance sector:

http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/16004.aspx